# simplest way to remove key value data from javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the simplest way to "afterpaypayovertime" key & value data from below object ?

```
let getPayments = available_payment_methods.filter(item => {
                return checkoutData.paymentOptions.find(value => item.code === value.payment_method);
              });
    
    //Output object
    getPayments = [
            {
                "payment_method": "afterpaypayovertime",
                "payment_label": "Afterpay"
            },
            {
                "payment_method": "paypal_express",
                "payment_label": "PayPal"
            },
            {
                "payment_method": "stripe_payments",
                "payment_label": "New Card"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Use `Array.protptype.filter` to remove elements from an array.

Comment: Hello @DrewReese thanks for the suggestion, could you please help me with above data ?

Comment: Which object are you trying to remove anything from? Do you mean you are trying to remove the first element from that `getPayments` array?

Comment: yes exaclty, i am trying to remove afterpaypayovertime from it

Comment: `getPayments.filter(el => el.payment_method !== "afterpaypayovertime")`

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer, i appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do something like this to get the desired results.

```
let newPaymentObj = getPayments.filter(paymentObject => paymentObject.payment_method !== 'afterpaypayovertime')
console.log(newPaymentObj)
```

the filter method provide you another array based on the condition that you pass to the callback function. In this case you are simply telling the filter method that you want to get every element in the array whose payment_method is not afterpaypayovertime

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can i also check some value like country code for example with above condition like

if country code is US then remove afterpay value

Comment: @devhs Yes, you can filter by any number of conditions.